# Calculate code to a new class.cs

Tags: c#, .net

i want to set my code to another class, example: A new class `AgeCalculate.cs`, How can I get the data from `AgeCalculate.cs` back to my `Button_Click` event.

Example:

`AgeCalculate Calculate = new AgeCalculate();`?

and from the class to Form1 =?

My code is now in `button_Click`.

```
        double startkapital = 0;
        double procentsats = 0;
        int år = 0;
        double kapital = 0;

        startkapital = int.Parse(sKapTxt.Text);
        procentsats = int.Parse(proSatsTxt.Text);

        kapital = startkapital;

        while (kapital < startkapital * 2)
        {
            kapital = kapital * (1 + procentsats / 100);
            år = år + 1;

            listBox1.Items.Add("Årtal: " + år);
            listBox1.Items.Add("Kapital: " + kapital + "kr ");
            listBox1.Items.Add(" ");
        }

        listBox1.Items.Add("Totalt antal år: " + år + "år ");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Total kapital: " + kapital + "kr ");
        listBox1.Items.Add(" ");

        double exaktaåret = år / ((100 + procentsats) / 100);

        listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Kapitalet fördubblades efter {0:0} år", exaktaåret));

        if (kapital >= 2 * startkapital)
        {
            listBox1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this.

Comment: This is not Visual Studio, stop tagging it with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, under your `button_Click` in your code behind `C#` event you will need to create an object of `AgeCalculate.cs`. I am not sure whether this is the correct way or not in `C#` but here it goes:

```
        AgeCalculate calc = new AgeCalculate();
```

Then you use the object you created to call a function which returns the age calculated like this:

```
        calc.FunctionName;
```

But before all, make sure in your class `AgeCalculate` there is a `Function` which has a `return` to return calculated age. And then once you do `calc.FunctionName` the calculated age will be returned.

**Example:**

**In AgeCalculate.cs**

```
public string calc(string value1)
{
    //calculate age
    String str = calculated age;
    return str;
}
```

**In `C#`**

```
AgeCalculate calculate = new AgeCalculate();

calculate.calc(pass the argument you will use to calculate age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `public property` in your AgeClass and get that property in your button click.